# Finding $n$ for which $H$ is a subgroup of the alternating group $A_n$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I tried to answer the following question:

Determine integers $n$ for which $H=\{\alpha \in A_n \mid \alpha^2 = e\}$ is a subgroup of $A_n$.

> Please could you tell me if my reasoning is correct?

My answer:

Note that $e$ and $h^{-1}$ are always in $H$ so the condition that might fail is $a,b\in H$ implies $ab \in H$.

So let $a,b \in H$. Note that $(ab)^2 = e$ if and only if $abab = e$ if and only if $ab = ba$. So $ab \in H$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ commute.

Note that two permutations $a,b$ in $S_n$ commute if and only if they are products of transposition $a_i, b_j$ such that either $a_i = b_j$ for some $i,j$ or $a_i$ and $b_j$ are disjoint.

The second condition is trivially satisfied if $n=1$ or $n=2$ since there is $\le 1$ transposition in these cases.

Otherwise note that

$$ (ab)(cd) \cdot (ab) (ce) = (ced)$$

and

$$ (ab) (ce) \cdot (ab) (cd) = (cde)$$

Hence if $n \ge 4$ we can find elements $a,b \in H$ such that $ab \notin H$.

The only case that remains to be investigated is $n=3$. In this case,

$$ A_3 = \{ e, (123)=(12)(13), (132)=(13)(12)\}$$

and we see that

$$ (12)(13) \cdot (13)(12) = e =(13)(12)\cdot  (12)(13)$$

so in the case $n=3$ is a subgroup.

To summarize: $H$ is a subgroup if and only if $n=1,2,3$.

Comment: Your argument about $ab \notin H$ can only exclude the case $n \geqslant 5$.

Comment: Hint: note that $H$ is closed under conjugation. You can immediately arrive then at finitely many such $n$. Then you can almost arrive at your conclusion.

Comment: @corindo Why? My example only uses $4$ numbers.

Comment: @corindo Lol, sorry. My example uses $5$ numbers.

Answer (score 1):

*To summarise the comments into an answer . . .*

Your argument saying that $ab\notin H$ excludes only the $n\ge 5$ cases (since you use five symbols).

The hint by @pGroups to conjugate amounts to observing that, for any $\sigma, \tau\in H$, where $\tau=(t_1t_2\dots t_n)$, we have

$$\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(t_1)\sigma(t_2)\dots \sigma(t_n)).$$